# django-cms and cmsplugin-news

Tags: django, content-management-system

I have been wrangling with Django for some weeks now, putting it down, picking it up, and now I am convinced that it's what I want to use. I got a site up and running with django-cms, but have a small challenge with cmsplugin-news.

I can input news items, list latest news items, and all works fine. However, when I click on an individual news item to view the detail, I get a 404 page not found error.

Here is my urls.py and settings.py file, respectively.

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('cmsplugin_news.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

SETTINGS.PY

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

gettext = lambda s: s

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

LANGUAGES = [('en', 'en'),('jp','jp')]
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 0

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'anadacms.db'),
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "http://portal.workpapers.pro/media/"

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'MYSECRETKEY'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.media.PlaceholderMediaMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('example.html', 'Basic Template'),
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

CMS_APPLICATIONS_URLS = (
    ('cmsplugin_news.urls', 'News'),
)

CMS_NAVIGATION_EXTENDERS = (
    ('cmsplugin_news.navigation.get_nodes', 'News navigation'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'mptt',
    'appmedia',
    'south',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'publisher',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'cmsplugin_facebook',
    'cmsplugin_news',
)
```

Here is a link to the urls.py file for the cmsplugin-news app:
https://bitbucket.org/MrOxiMoron/cmsplugin-news/src/03ba1b86624b/cmsplugin_news/urls.py

Comment: Whats the URL that's giving the 404? It will be failing either because it doesn't match a urlpattern or because a view is throwing a 404. We need to work out which...

Comment: Spacedman >> Thank you. In the views.py for the cmsplugin-news part of the app, the file is blank. For clarification, will add the urls.py file for the cmsplugin-news app.

Comment: To better answer your question, the url that's throwing a 404 is: http://www.mydomain.com/news/2011/04/01/article-slug/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very simple: The cms.urls should **always** be last in your urlconf because it eats every request.

Changing your urls.py to this should fix it::

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include('cmsplugin_news.urls')),
    # MUST BE LAST!!!
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```